# Algolia React CurrentRefinements useCurrentRefinements

Tags: reactjs, onclick, algolia

Hi so I'm trying to make a custom CurrentRefinements component. Almost everything works except the refine(Clears a single refinement and triggers a new search)

Heres my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCurrentRefinements } from "react-instantsearch-hooks-web";
import AlgoliaClearRefinements from "./AlgoliaClearRefinements";


const AlgoliaCurrentRefinements= ({  }) => {

    const { items, refine } = useCurrentRefinements({
        excludedAttributes: ['categories'],
    });
return (
    <>
    {items[0]?.refinements.map((refinement, refinementIndex) => (
        <li key={refinementIndex}>
            <button onClick={() =>refine(refinement.value)} > //{/* not working */}
                <div className="font-normal">Categories: </div>
                <div className="capitalize font-bold">{refinement.label}</div>
            </button>
        </li>
       ))}
    </>
  )
};
```

So its the Button that calls the refine function that is not working. If I console log

```
<button className="border-2" onClick={() => console.log(`clicked ${refinement.value}`)}>
```

I get the right value out that I want to remove from the refinement.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, there dockumentation said it:

refine#
type: (value: CurrentRefinementsItem) => void
Clears a single refinement and triggers a new search.

I though, I have to send only a string the like this the value:

```
<button onClick={() =>refine(refinement.value)} >
```

But Algolia here want the objec. This works!!!

```
<button onClick={() =>refine(refinement)} >
```